# Kernighan–Lin algorithm and multiple gain functions

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms

I want to know if there is an algorithm like KERNIGHAN-LIN for graph partitioning that can handle several (different) gain functions.

Is there some technique to combine gain functions in one algorithm?

The KL algorithm and its gain function is defined here for example:

http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~demmel/cs267/lecture18/lecture18.html#link_4.2

Comment: Could you please provide some motivation and explain why you are interested in this question?

Comment: My guess would be that the OP wants to use the Kernighan-Lin algorithm to do multi-criterion optimization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kim and Moon (2004) compare variants of Kernighan-Lin which combine the usual gain and a lock-based gain, which is relative to the locked vertices. You can combine two gain functions in the range $-n\ldots n$ using an implementation of Fiduccia-Matheyses with $O(n^2)$ buckets.

Kim, Moon, [Lock-gain based Graph Partitioning](http://dx.doi.org/10.1023/B%3aHEUR.0000019985.94952.eb), J Heuristics, 10, 37-57, 2004.